# Representation of a simple for loop in JSTL/EL

Tags: jsp, for-loop, jstl, el

I need to represent the following `for` loop (in Java context) in JSTL/EL.

```
for (int i = 6; i <= 15; i++) {
  System.out.print(i+"\t");
}
```

It would display the following output.

```
6      7      8       9       10       11       12       13       14       15
```

How can I do the same in JSTL/EL? I have no precise idea about it. I'm just trying the following.

```
<c:forEach begin="6" end="15" varStatus="loop">
    <c:out value="${loop.count}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

and it would obviously display the following output.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

It's not that I want. I need to display numbers between `6` and `15` (i.e between the specified range). I need to put such a concept to implement paging in my web application. Can I do this using EL?

---

`\t` in this statement `System.out.print(i+"\t");` is not significant.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<c:forEach begin="6" end="15" var="val">
    <c:out value="${val}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Or the following:

```
<c:forEach begin="6" end="15" varStatus="loop">
    <c:out value="${loop.current}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Or the following:

```
<c:forEach begin="6" end="15" varStatus="loop">
    <c:out value="${loop.index}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have just come across the following solution.

```
<c:forEach begin="6" end="15" var="i">
    <c:out value="${i}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

I have removed the `varStatus="loop"` attribute and added the `var="i"` attribute. It produces the following output.

```
6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Exactly as I wanted. The idea came from [here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=nKpvsy8mAZMC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=display%20range%20of%20numbers%20using%20for%20loop%20in%20jstl%20el&source=bl&ots=-63cRJRdk7&sig=Os7Rn3HMUEls4RBvbXCPBC913Ck&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jY4TUMnECYnIrQeaxIDYBQ&ved=0CF4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=display%20range%20of%20numbers%20using%20for%20loop%20in%20jstl%20el&f=false).