# Is there a way to get the index of each item in a list being passed to JSTL c:forEach

Tags: foreach, jstl

If I use the JSTL forEach loop to display a list of all returned items from my controller, Is there a way to output an index number for each item that is returned in the list?

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="#{Controller.allItems}" >

    <tr><td>{index number here???} : #{item.name}</td></tr>    
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11699191/1391249

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Representation of a simple for loop in JSTL/EL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698993/representation-of-a-simple-for-loop-in-jstl-el)

Answer (score 3):

That's what the attribute [varStatus](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html) is for:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="#{Controller.allItems}" varStatus="status" >
     <tr><td>${status.index} : #{item.name}</td></tr>    
</c:forEach>
```

VarStatus contains many other Attributes as well:

- begin
- end
- **index**
- step
- even
- odd
- first
- last